# How to run different tcp servers on the same machine

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I want to write a n-tier application, where the server part can be hosted on the customer site or our company can host the server part (for each customer) on our machine (over the internet).

When our company is hosting the customers server part. We then have to run the same server application multiple times (for each customer). I don't want to change and maintain the port numbers for every server instance. 
So my question is: Is it possible to run the same server app with the same port mapping on the same machine? Just specifying a unique uri/url in the server app? like:

1. http://10.0.0.127:8090/customer_1/
2. http://10.0.0.127:8090/customer_2/

I am using Indy components for client/server communication.

Comment: You said TCP servers in your title, but shown HTTP URIs in your post body. What are they ? But generally no, only one instance of an application can bind to a specific port.

Comment: Why do you need to run multiple server instances? Generally servers are specifically designed to be able to provide data to multiple clients. Now you should provide us with the infromation about which components do you actually use and don't only say Indy becouse Indy component suite offer a whole bunch of different components which offeres diferent way of usage from component to component.

Comment: As TLama said, no you can't. That being said, you can run a service that listens for the URL's and forward the request towards another server (or same server, other port)

Comment: @SilverWarior: "Why do I need to run multiple server instances?" I want to develop a client/server app (n-tier architecture over the internet). That application can be hosted by the customer (one Server + DB and multiply clients). That's no problem. But when the customer doesn't have it's one server I want to host the server part for him. Since I don't want to run a full Windows installation for each customer, I just want to run his server in a single windows environment. In order to avoid to rewrite the server part for hosting mutliple customer DBs, I want to reuse the existing server part.

Comment: @TLama: I am a newbie in that area. Isn't http the protocol on top of tcp? The http url was just a sample.

Comment: @markus_ja Then I'm afraid that I must dissapoint you. You can't make multiple applications to listen on same port. Why? Becouse as soon as one aplication reads the data from that port the data is erased from network buffer so it is no longer available for other aplications. This means that trying to something like this you are creating a race condition about which application wil read that data first.

Comment: @SilverWarior: "Which component to I use?" I didn't start the project, so I am open for suggestion which Indy components are the best to make the job.

Comment: @markus_ja I see only two posible solutions for your problem. One is to use solution that whosrdaddy suggested and redirect the data to correct server application based on the initial URL. But I personally would not suggest using of this solution as it creates aditional load to your server becouse server needs to redirect all data from one port to another. The best solution is the one that you are trying to avoid. And that is changing your server part to be able to handle multiple clients databases at once.

Comment: @markus_ja Oh another solution would be to set up your computer so that ti can run each server instance for each of your customers in its own virtual enviroment like it is done with web hosting on proffesional servers. This approach is similar to the URL redirection one but since each server application is ran in its own virtual enviroment it does provide better security as one server application can not interact with another. But I strongly disadvice of using this approach unless you truely have a proffesional server hardware at your disposal or you Will be facing serious performance isues.

Comment: @markus_ja by the way what kind of sesion managment are you using? Becouse if you intend to host server application for multiple users from one computer you should seriously consider security risks. So if your sesion managment is poor or you have none then it means that you are risking for someone to break into your system and acces some others clients data.

Comment: @SilverWarior: "...its own virtual enviroment...". Actually our server allready runs on a server farm where we can choose the hardware on demand. Is it the same? In my current situation I need a windows license for every machine. Also renting such full enviroment costs a lot per month. Which nobody wants to buy for your tiny software. ... or do you mean something different with "virtual environment"?

Comment: @markus_ja When talking about virtual enviroment I had the idea of creating your own virtual server farm through the use of some virtualization software. That is if you would be setting this up on standard computer that acts as server.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Would it be possible to create a CGI exe or ISAPI dll and use it in MS IIS7? So for every customer I create a new "Folder" with the same server application (same .exe or .dll in every "Folder"). So I just need xcopy my files and configure IIS. Since there I can create my own url.

Comment: @markus_ja How would you determine from your one URL to which server application the recieved data or command is intended to? You either need to have uniqe URL's for each of your clients or use one server aplication which is capable to determine to which client does the data or command belongs with the use of sesion managing

Comment: @SilverWarior: I create a physical folder and put my ISAP dll or CGI exe file there. Then I add that folder to IIS, convert it "to application" and give that node a name or rename it. With that name I can access my server module (dll/exe). e.g. IIS is listening on port 8090 and my folder or node name is "customer_x" then to url in my client would be "htt p://x.x.x.x:8090/customer_x"

Comment: Yes, HTTP mostly uses TCP as a transport layer. But back to those URIs. You could have a single HTTP server instance (you can use e.g. ready made HTTP server projects) that will simply redirect requests by the (URI redirect) rules to another HTTP server instances (running each on different port, because it's impossible to bind to the same port on the same IP for the same protocol, as we already said).

Comment: @TLama: Thanks. I understand. Since I don't want to use different ports (I am afraid of the maintaince when the user base growth). I thought about using IIS as posted above. There I can use different urls with same port. But I hope I can load ISAPI dlls with the same name multiple times (but in different folders). Otherwise I have to use CGI exe. So I can reuse the same code base for the server, just compiling it for different output.

Answer (score 2):

The only way multiple servers can listen on the same port on the same machine is if they are bound to different IP addresses.  Otherwise, you have to use different ports.

The alternative is to host just one HTTP server and utilize HTTP 1.1's virtual host feature (via the [`Host`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23) header, which is a *required* header in all HTTP 1.1 requests) to differentiate between different customer sites on the same server, eg:

1. http://customer1.myserver.com:8090/ generates:

   ```
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: customer1.myserver.com:8090
   ```
2. http://customer2.myserver.com:8090/ generates:

   ```
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: customer1.myserver.com:8090
   ```

Your server can look at the `Host` header to know which customer site to access.

Read [RFC 2616 Section 19.6.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.6.1.1) for more information:

[Changes to Simplify Multi-homed Web Servers and Conserve IP Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.6.1.1)